# assign an object in array of objects c++

Tags: c++, arrays

in this code I am trying to add some objects to basees and it compiles but will crash inside addbase function,can someone tell me why?(I know that allocating memory without freeing it is not good but I think it does not affect the behavior of my code here)

```
class base
{
  string a;
  public:
    void setstring(string);
    string showstring(){ return a; }
};

void base::setstring(string ss)
{
  a=ss;
}

class pointerclass 
{
  public:
    base *basees;
    pointerclass() {base *basees=new base[5]; }
    void addbase(base,int);
};

void pointerclass::addbase(base ab,int i)
{
  //will crash here
  basees[i] = ab;
}

int main()
{
  base a,b,c;
  a.setstring("something");
  pointerclass aaa;
  aaa.addbase(a,0);
  cout<<aaa.basees[0].showstring();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: That previous comment should read "you should [edit] your question" - something obviously went wrong with the expansion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the constructor of `pointerclass` you do the following:

```
base *basees=new base[5];
```

This declares a new local variable called `basees` within the constructor, it allocates memory for it, and then control returns from the constructor, forgetting that the local variable ever existed.  (Memory leak.)

As a result, the member field of `pointerclass` called `basees` is never initialized.

So, the first time you try to assign something to `pointerclass.basees`, your program blows up.

What you meant to do within your constructor is the following:

```
basees=new base[5];
```

Comment: Note that your compiler will probably have warned you about this unused variable.

Answer (score 0):

In `pointerclass(){base *basees=new base[5];}` you allocate not the member `basees`, but a variable `basees` which lives only inside brackets.

Answer (score 0):

you should allocate memory for member pointer `basess`